# How do you disable auto-start apps just for remote sessions?

Tags: remote-desktop, autostart, session

There's a lot of answers on how to disable auto-starting of applications for a single user or for globally on a system. However, most auto-start applications, you do want to start for the console user, but not for remote users.

Does anyone know if it's possible to disable for all remote sessions like via remote desktop? For example, there's no reason why the bluetooth indicator should start for a remote session.

Thanks